# How to create a timezone-aware time object in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I need to add timezones (for example, New York) to a time object I create

Like this :

```
import datetime
import pytz

mytime = datetime.time(12,00,00)
time_zone = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
local_time = time_zone.localize(mytime)
```

but I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 323, in localize
    loc_dt = dt + delta
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pytz
import datetime

time_zone = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
local_time = datetime.time(hour=12, tzinfo=time_zone)
```